# Delphi XE7 Android - No mapping for unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page

Tags: android, delphi, unicode

I am trying to fetch an image from a SOAP Web Service into a Delphi XE7 Android App using TSoapAttachment component.

```
procedure TTabbedwithNavigationForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
Var img: TSOAPAttachment;
    strm: TStream;  
begin
    img:= Service.GetImage('d:\pictures\pic.jpg');   <== Error on this line
    if img <> nil then begin
        strm:= TMemoryStream.Create;
        img.SaveToStream(strm);
        strm.Position:= 0;
        Image1.Bitmap.LoadFromStream(strm);
        strm.Free;
        DeleteFile(img.CacheFile);
    end;
end;
```

The Web Service is implemented as follows:

```
function TMyService.GetImage(const imgfile: AnsiString) : TSOAPAttachment; stdcall;

begin
    Result:= TSOAPAttachment.Create;
    Result.SetSourceFile(imgfile);
end;
```

This runs fine on Win32, but on Android gives error "No mapping for Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page" on the *Service.GetImage* line.

Comment: `AnsiString` is not a type that the mobile compilers (e.g. for Android and iOS) know. Only the Win32, Win64 and OS X compilers know it. I assume it is marshalled as `MarshaledAString`, and that is not compatible with `UnicodeString` (aka `string`), since data might get lost.

Comment: Thanks @Rudy for your reply. My Web Service is ison a Windows m/c under Apache. I originally has `String` but I changed it to `AnsiString` after getting this error. I have changed it back to `String` but the problem remains.